# Rooted android device but getting "Security exception: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android"

Tags: root-access, permissions, magisk, nexus-6p, airplane-mode

I've got a nexus 6P running stock Android 8.1 which is rooted using Magisk (verified by runnign `adb shell su`).

When turning airplane mode on/off using adb (as per these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40271379) the following exception is returned:

```
$ adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
$ adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE flg=0x400000 }
Security exception: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=6484, uid=2000

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=6484, uid=2000
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19204)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19842)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runSendBroadcast(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:621)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:154)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:15021)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:594)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:492)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:4243)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2919)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

What needs to happen for adb to be able to turn airplane mode on and off?

Comment: Have you tried sending that broadcast as root user or as system user?

Comment: System, how do you send it as a root user?

Comment: Get into shell using `adb shell`, then `su -c "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"`.

Comment: Awesome, that works!

Comment: Good to know. Please do post it as a self-answer.

Comment: Your problem was asked in a comment on that stackoverflow.com question and somebody had provided the same solution as I did here. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506591/turning-airplane-mode-on-via-adb/40271379#comment86503606_40271379